# JUnit/Mockito: How to mock or create a private member variable

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I have a private String variable filePath that will be set in the SpringBoot's `execute(..)` method and then the value will be used in another method that will be called from inside this `execute(..)`.

```
@Component("filebatchjobtask")
public class FileBatchJobTask extends BaseFileBatchJobTask implements Tasklet {


    private String filePath;   // PRIVATE VARIABLE THAT WILL BE USED IN A CALL 

    private static final CalLogger LOGGER = CalLoggerFactory.getLogger(FileBatchJobTask.class);

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(final StepContribution stepContribution, final ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        // INITIALIZE PRIVATE VARIABLE HERE
        filePath  = chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters().get(Constants.FILEPATH).toString();
        
        processeFile();  // METHOD CALL WHERE FILEPATH INITIALIZED ABOVE WILL BE USED

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processeFile() throws IOException {
        LOGGER.warn("FileBatchJobTask:processeFile():: Directory to process files: " + filePath);
        File[] filelist = geteFiles(filePath);  // THIS IS THE CALL I WANT TO MOCK
        if (filelist == null || filelist.length < 1) {
            LOGGER.warn("FileBatchJobTask: No eFiles available to process");
            return;
        }

        LOGGER.warn("Total number of files to process: " + filelist.length);
}
```

It's corresponding test below:

```
//@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FileBatchJobTaskTest extends BaseFileBatchJobTaskTest {

    @InjectMocks
    FileBatchJobTask fileBatchJobTask;

    @Override
    BaseFileBatchJobTask createFileBatchJobTask() {
        return fileBatchJobTask;
    }

    @Test
    public void processeFile() {
        BaseFileBatchJobTask batchJobTask = Mockito.spy(createFileBatchJobTask());
        
        // THIS resourceDir is the I want to use instead of filePath variable in tests here and pick file from this test resource path
        Path resourceDir = Paths.get("src", "test", "resources", "data", "validation");
        resourcePath = resourceDir.toFile().getAbsolutePath();

        File fileDir = new File(resourcePath);
        File[] files = fileDir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(final File pathname) {
                String name = pathname.getName().toLowerCase();
                return name.endsWith(".xml") && pathname.isFile();
            }
        });
        doReturn(files).when(batchJobTask).geteFiles(anyString());  // THIS IS THE CALL I AM TRYING TO MOCK
        

        try {
            
            fileBatchJobTask.processeFile();
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        } catch (...) {

        }

}
```

This is the base class

```
class BaseFileBatchJobTask {

    protected File[] geteFiles(final String eFileDirPath) {
        File fileDir = new File(eFileDirPath);   // NPE as eFileDirPath is null
        File[] files = fileDir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(final File pathname) {
                String name = pathname.getName().toLowerCase();
                return name.endsWith(".xml") && pathname.isFile();
            }
        });

        return files;
    }

}
```

`ERROR`: I am getting NPE as when the test is run, getEFiles() is executed and filePath is null. Since I am mocking, it shouldn't go inside the actual implementation of the method. However, seems it's not being mocked as expected, so need help in figuring out the issue.

Also looked up a lot of SO posts but couldn't figure out the issue so please don't mark as duplicate if you don't know the answer :)

Comment: @Progman I updated fileBatchJobTask to be as spy on Kathrin's comment below. I am not sure what I am supposed to do here but just trying hit and trial ways. Do you have idea on how its correctly done?

Comment: So I updated and only kept the spy for `batchJobTask` one and not the `fileBatchJobTask`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `processeFile()` on the spied version of your jobTask, not on the original one. Think about a spy being a wrapper around the spied object, that intercepts the mocked calls.

For short, just use `batchJobTask` inside the `try-catch` block like this:

```
    try {    
    
        batchJobTask.processeFile();
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    } catch (...) {

    }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and does it mean like this `fileBatchJobTask = Mockito.spy(fileBatchJobTask);`. Still the same error.